# Python a &= b meaning?

Tags: python, operators, ampersand, in-place

What does the `&=` operator mean in Python, and can you give me a working example?

[I am trying to understand the `__iand__` operator.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.iand)

I just don't know what `&=` means and have looked online but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 47):

### What does `a &= b` mean?

This depends on the implementation for the types of `a` and `b`, but semantics are essentially that

```
a &= b
```

is the update of `a` with its "AND" for `b`. That "AND" operation could be a set intersection, a binary AND operation, or some other operation that can be implemented by a programmer.

So there are multiple ways of implementing it.

In the following sections, I demonstrate `__and__` and `__iand__` and give multiple examples of types for which there are different semantics below (`set`, in which the `a` object is mutated in-place, and `frozenset` and `int` which are immutable, so the variable `a` is now pointing to the new object).

### Explanation

Understandable that you can't find much reference on it. [I find it hard to get references on this too, but they exist.](http://books.google.com/books?id=H9emM_LGFDEC&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=python%20%22__iand__%22&source=bl&ots=Z9cJbKJcnS&sig=1NCzV9lG_e6VFVK1J0MxeFG0LN8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=T3TdUtLzMvC1sASOt4H4CA&ved=0CGQQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=python%20%22__iand__%22&f=false)

The `i` in `iand` means *in-place*, so it's the in-place operator for `&`. `&=` calls the `__iand__` operator, if it is implemented. If not implemented, it is the same as `x = x & y`.

### Built-in Example, Sets:

It's primarily used to update the intersection of built-in set types:

```
>>> a = set('abc') 
>>> a &= set('cbe')
>>> a
set(['c', 'b'])
```

which is the same as:

```
>>> a = set('abc')
>>> a.__iand__(set('cbe'))
set(['c', 'b'])
```

It is very similar to calling the `set.intersection_update` method, and would be used in control flow as you would do an in-place update of any object or variable (if the object is immutable).

### Unimplemented Built-in Example

The less commonly used immutable frozenset object would be replaced in memory on the inplace update, and the variable name would point to the new object in memory.

```
>>> a = frozenset('abc')
>>> a &= set('bce')
>>> a
frozenset({'c', 'b'})
```

In this case, *since* frozenset doesn't implement an `__iand__` method,

```
>>> a = frozenset('abc')
>>> a.__iand__(set('cbe'))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#160>", line 1, in <module>
    a = frozenset('abc'); a.__iand__(set('cbe'))
AttributeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute '__iand__'
```

it **is (*nearly) identical** to

```
a = a & set('bce')
```

*(I say *nearly* because if you examine the bytecode, you'll see that the underlying implementation treats sets and frozensets the same, even though frozensets don't have `__iand__`, and sets do, because each calls `INPLACE_AND`, at least for compiled functions.)

### Built-in Example, Binary Flags:

Similar to Sets, we can use the `&=` to update the intersection of binary option flags where the value for `True` is `1`. Below, we demonstrate that the "[binary AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)", (akin to intersection) of the binary numbers `1110` and `1011` is `1010`:

```
>>> option_flags = int('1110', 2)
>>> option_flags
14
>>> option_flags &= int('1011', 2)
>>> option_flags
10
>>> bin(option_flags)
'0b1010'
```

Since `int` objects are not mutable, like the `frozenset` example, this actually only reassigns the variable `option_flags` to the newly calculated value.

Comment: So its the intersection between 2 elements.

Comment: @Shmack - I have written a new intro to specifically answer that comment.

Answer (score 15):

Contrary to some of the other answers, `a &= b` is *not* shorthand for `a = a & b`, though I admit it often behaves similarly for built-in immutable types like integers.

`a &= b` can call the special method [`__iand__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iand__) if available.  To see the difference, let's define a custom class:

```
class NewIand(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __and__(self, other):
        return self.x & other.x
    def __iand__(self, other):
        return 99
```

After which we have

```
>>> a = NewIand(1+2+4)
>>> b = NewIand(4+8+16)
>>> a & b
4
>>> a = a & b
>>> a
4
```

but

```
>>> a = NewIand(1+2+4)
>>> b = NewIand(4+8+16)
>>> a &= b
>>> a
99
```

Answer (score 8):

It is a shorthand for:

```
a = a & b
```

`&` is [bitwise `and`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) (see link for further explanation) if `a` and `b` are either `int` or `long`.

Otherwise, the statement is equivalent to:

```
a = a.__iand__(b)
```

if `__iand__` is defined for `a`.

Comment: @JBurnham like `a += b` is a shorthand for 'a = a + b`. To be more appropriate, I would say, "like &= in C#".

Answer (score 4):

to put it in simple terms. Under the hood it does bit-wise binary operation.

for example 5 in binary is 0101
and 3 in binary is 0011

now do "And" operation between them (when both are 1 the result is one, 0 otherwise) and you will get binary 0001 which means 1 in decimal.

```
x = 5
x &= 3
print(x)
output >>> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very similar to `+=`. It means

```
a = a & b
```

Answer (score 2):

**It means bitwise AND operation.**

Example :

```
x = 5
x &= 3 #which is similar to x = x & 3
print(x)
```

**Answer : 1**

How does it works?

```
The binary of 5 is : 0 1 0 1
The binary of 3 is : 0 0 1 1

AND operation : (If both sides are 1/True then result is 1/True)

0 1 0 1  #Binary of 5
0 0 1 1  #Binary of 3
---------------------
0 0 0 1  #Binary of 1
```

**So, the answer is 1**

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I focused on `__and__` and `__iand__`, but the below description works exactly the same for any other combination of operators and their *in place* counterparts.

## tl;dr

|  | `&` / `__and__` | `&=` / `__iand__` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Side effects (e.g. mutation of one of the arguments) | Virtually possible, however discouraged | Highly expected |
| Result | New instance | Same instance |

## Longer answer

What's important to understand is that `__and__` function is supposed to be *pure*, that means it shouldn't have side effects, and it must return the same result for the very same arguments.

```py
a = 5
b = 3

print(a & b)
print(a.__and__(b))
print(int.__and__(a, b))
```

No matter how many times you invoke the function, the result is always `1`. Since the function doesn't have side effects, it feels natural to return a value from it because the result must be stored somehow. Besides, `a & b` is an expression so it's expected to return a result.

On the other side we have `__iand__`. The `i` on the beginning stands for *in place*. For most of the time it is invoked as a consequence of using `&=` operator which in fact is a so called "augmented assignment" operator, and the keyword here is "assignment". Assignments in Python are statements, that means they do not produce results, as opposed to expressions, but can have side effects. The expected side effect of `&=` is changing whatever the operator has on its left-hand side.

Take a look at the following code:

```py
a = 5
b = 3

print(a &= b)
```

If you try it, it won't work because `print` expects an expression argument. But, you can do this:

```py
print(a.__iand__(b))
```

However, this will fail too because `int` doesn't implement `__iand__` (understandable, primitives are immutable). If so, why the below code works and outputs `1`?

```py
a &= b
print(a)
```

When Python can't find `__iand__`, it will expand `a &= b` to `a = a & b`, so it in fact invokes `a.__and__(b)`, and overwrites the content of the `a` variable. A mutable integer type could look like this:

```py
class MutableInt:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __and__(self, other):
        return MutableInt(self.value & other.value)

    def __iand__(self, other):
        self.value &= other.value
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
```